# Why is my linked list sort changing the values of the list?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

Question is pretty much self-explanatory.

Here's my code:

```
LinkedList* llSort(LinkedList* l) { // this function is changing the ascii values for some reason

LinkedList* tmpPtr = l; // tmpPtr is pointing to the beginning of the LinkedList
LinkedList* tmpNext = l->next; // tmpNext is pointing to the second entry in the LinkedList

int tmp;

/* while we are not at the end of the LinkedList */
while(tmpNext != NULL) {

/* and while tmpNext isn't pointing backwards */
while(tmpNext != tmpPtr) {

  /* if the frequency of tmpNext is less than the frequency of tmpPtr */
  if(tmpNext->value->freq < tmpPtr->value->freq) {

    /* set tmp = to tmpPtr's freq */
    tmp = tmpPtr->value->freq;

    /* set tmpPtr's freq equal to tmpNext's freq */
    tmpPtr->value->freq = tmpNext->value->freq;

        /* set tmpNext's freq equal to tmp, which is the value of the original frequency */
        tmpNext->value->freq = tmp;
      }

      /* set tmpPtr equal to it's next value */
      tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
    }
tmpPtr = l;
    tmpNext = tmpNext->next;
  }
return tmpPtr;
}
```

LinkedListsH.h: Creates a structure of pointers to HuffmanTrees and pointers to the next value in the LinkedList.

```
#include "huffman.h"

typedef struct linkedListNode {
    HuffmanTree* value;
    struct linkedListNode* next;
} LinkedList;\
```

And the HuffmanTree structure.

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //standard library
#include <string.h>

typedef struct huffmanNode {
  char c;
  int freq;
  struct huffmanNode* left;
  struct huffmanNode* right;
} HuffmanTree;
```

When I run this code, the llSort method sorts the LinkedList correctly, but it also changes the ascii values of the Huffman chars. I've walked through it a couple different times and I can't figure out why this is happenening. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you sort the `freq`s while leaving the `c` alone, then the mapping of `c` to `freq` will change.

Comment: So I've a question. Why are you swapping *values* in your list nodes rather than swapping around the *nodes* via pointer adjustment? Isn't that somewhat the point of linked list sorting; that you can sort without touching values.

Comment: Can you show us how you're populating the values?

Comment: @WhozCraig, I'm working on switching my sorting method to swapping pointers rather than moving other things around, so I'll update my question once I finish or have more problems. Thanks guys!

Comment: If I'm going to be *picky* and add some subjective comments: 1. I would do some re-naming `l => list`, `tmpPtr => head`, `tmpNext => next`, `tmp => freq`, I'd also say `return list;` instead of `return tmpPtr;` as that is what in fact is done. By returning `tmpPtr` one have to read over the code to check if start node changes. 2. I would not hide the fact that I'm dealing with structs and removed the typedef's. But as said. Subjective and only as a comment.

Comment: @Nannooskeeska Either an insertion sort or a bubble sort on your linked list will probably work. I can't imagine its terribly long. If course, you could always totally punt and load up a dynamic vector of pointers containing every node pointer in your linked list, ram it through `qsort()` with a creatively constructed comparator, then walk the pointer array and wire up the newly ordered linked list after `qsort` finishes chewing on it. Depending on your performance needs, that may be worth it.

Comment: `LinkedList* tmpNext = l->next; // tmpNext is pointing to the second entry ...` Unless l==NULL.

Comment: A hideous (i.e. no error checking) version of the `qsort()` method I described above [can be seen here](http://pastebin.com/HKgSSCZy). I never even compiled, much less tested it, so YMMV. But I hope it gives you alternative ideas. Best of luck.